# Karate - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Karate> to Class<? extends Runner

Tags: java, maven, karate

I am able to see this issue when I write my java class using Karate language.
[Exception when I write the java class using Karate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c17Tc.png)

**Solution :**

Add these dependencies to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: a note to everyone landing here. the answers here contain bad advice. if you have mixed up junit4 and junit5 this is not a karate issue. "downgrading" is most likely NOT the right solution

Answer (score -1):

Add these dependencies to the pom.xml for resolving the issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also add this import statement to the java class

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error while using 'com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;'
and it was solved by downgrading version from junit5 to junit4 as below

'import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;'